# How to Avoid Temporal Coupling With Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Consider the following example:

```
// saveThings.js
import * as services from './services';

export default (a, b) => {
  return {
    aSaved: services.save(a),
    bSaved: services.save(b)
  };
};
```

And a test:

```
// test.js
import * as services from './services';
import saveThings from './saveThings';

jest.mock('./services');

test('saves things', () => {
  services.save.mockReturnValueOnce(true)
  services.save.mockReturnValueOnce(false)
  const result = saveThings(1, 2)
  expect(result).toEqual({aSaved: true, bSaved: false})
  expect(services.save).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)
  expect(services.save).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2)
});
```

This does the job, It verifies the value I expect and that the correct service calls were made.

However, it suffers from a tragic flaw. I have accidentally introduced a temporal dependency between the code and the test. The test is demanding that the code call save on `a` and `b` in a particular order. However, as you can see, this is not important. If the order changes, the function still works as expected, but the test breaks.

This is an over-specification that will lead to fragility, which is the major reason that tests rot over time.

Is there a way to handle this with Jest? With sinon you can specify the arguments when you define the expectations. Is there a way to do something like that in Jest?

Comment: Rather than using `mockReturnValueOnce`, could you rather simply [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) the function and have that method check the input against `1` and `2` to know what to return?  At which point the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Taplar - You mean like this? `services.save.mockImplementation(x => x === 1)`. It works, but it's hard to grok, and could get really thorny for complex cases. Thanks.

Comment: What is "grok"?

Comment: Why not just have the mock return the input it received? Then ditch the `toHaveBeenCalledWith` assertions. The `toEqual` assertion would indirectly verify that the mock had been called correctly, right?

Comment: @Taplar https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok

Comment: @Taplar - The other shortcoming with that approach is not having matchers. I want specify what each call should return based on it's args matching a combination of exact values and/or matchers as you do with the `toHaveBeenCalledWith`.

Comment: Logical checks could always be written against the `arguments` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. [`jest-when`](https://github.com/timkindberg/jest-when) was created for this. The API is like:

```
when(services.save).calledWith(a).mockReturnValueOnce(true)
when(services.save).calledWith(b).mockReturnValueOnce(false)
```